# Where does String s= s1+s2;(s1 & s2 are String literals) returns from? heap or pool

Tags: java, string

```
    String s1="abc";                 //pool
    String s2="abccde";              //pool
    String s3="cde";                 //pool
    String s4=s1+s3;                 //heap
    String s5=new String("abccde");  //heap

    System.out.println(s2==s4);
    System.out.println(s4==s5);
    System.out.println(s2==s5);
```

I was expecting false,true false   BUT got all false in result. While i tried using .intern(); in s4 i got true for s2==s4 meaning after intern(); it returned from pool so earlier it was returning from heap, so why not s4==s5 is giving true?

Thanks

Comment: The string pool is part the heap. All objects reside in the heap.

Comment: Because s5 is a new String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because new always creates a new object and has no chance of returning one from a pool? It's a constructor, not a factory method like intern().

Answer (score 0):

None of those will ever identity equal `s5`, as you explicitly used the `new` keyword.

If the compiler can determine that `s1` and `s3` are literal constants, it will treat the concat as a literal [constant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#d5e30892). However, it is not a given that the compiler can make that determination.